# ¿Porque me da como resultado el total de los caracteres?

Tags: java, string

La idea, es contar el número de veces que aparece una letra en una frase; en este caso es la b,pero me da como resultado el total de todas las letras

```
    char x='b';
    String y="hola";

            int n=0;
            for(int i=0;i<y.length();i++) {
                if(y.charAt(i)==x);
                n++;

            }
            System.out.println(n);  
        }
```

Comment: Debes hacerle un split() a tu string para dividirlo en cada letra.

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que tenés un punto y coma después del if, entonces el contador se incrementa en cada iteración.
Deberías hacer algo así:

```
char x='b';
String y="hola";
int n=0; 
for(int i=0;i<y.length();i++) {
    if(y.charAt(i)==x)
        n++;
}
System.out.println(n);
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: esta es la respuesta correcta. El punto coma hace un no-op en el if, voto positivo